# Is it possible to unify these two expressions into one?

Tags: notation

I have the following expressions $\forall n \in \Bbb N$:

$E = f(n)-1$ if $n \gt 1$

$E = f(n)+1$ if $n = 0$

I would like to have only one expression like this:

$E = f(n)+$(some nice notation able to unify both cases into one)

> Is there a notation able to unify the expressions into one? $n=0$ is an special case. Initially I do not think it is possible but there might be a notation capable of doing it and I do not see it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E = f(n) + \dfrac{|n - 1/2|}{1/2 - n}$

Comment: oh cool, I did not saw it at all! Basically any positive value lower than $1$, like $1/2$, or for instance $0.9999999$ will do the trick. Thank you!!! you saved my day.