# A function can provide the complete set of Euler primes via a Mill's-like constant. Is it useful or just a curiosity?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, constants

The following $f(m,n)$ function provides the complete set of Euler primes ([OEIS A196230](https://oeis.org/A196230)):

> $$f(m,n)=m^2-m+[\lfloor E^{2^n} \rfloor - {\lfloor E^{2^{n-1}} \rfloor}^2 +\frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n)}]$$
>
> $$E = 2.893392257682316134127494663$$
>
> $$n\in[0,5] \in \Bbb N\ \ \ \ m = [1..(\lfloor E^{2^n} \rfloor  - {\lfloor E^{2^{n-1}} \rfloor}^2+\frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n)})] \in \Bbb N$$

$E$ is a [Mills-like constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) I have calculated which is related with Euler's "Lucky" numbers ([OEIS A014556](https://oeis.org/A014556), $n$ such that $x^2-x+n$ is prime for $m=0..n-1$). Initially I did not find this constant in any bibliography or reference, and initially it seemed a nice use of a Mills-like constant. So here are the calculations (the questions are at the end):

> Def. Euler's "Lucky" constant $E = 2.893392257682316134127494663$

This constant is such that:

> $\lfloor E^{2^n} \rfloor -(\lfloor E^{2^{n-1}} \rfloor)^2+\frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n}$
>
> for $n=[0..5]$  provides the sequence of Euler's "Lucky" numbers $\{ 2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 41 \}$ in the same growing order.

Euler's lucky constant $E$ is a Mill's like constant obtained by the encapsulation of [Euler's "Lucky" numbers](https://oeis.org/A014556) into integers $E_n$ of $[N,(N+1)^2]$ intervals. This provides a representing function of Euler's "Lucky" numbers for $n=[0..5]$.

The calculation of the sequence of elements that will be the lower bounds of the $[N,(N+1)^2]$ intervals is as follows:

$E_0=(2)$

$E_1=3+1+({E_1}^2) = 8$

$E_2=5+1+({E_2}^2) = 70$

$E_3=11+1+({E_3}^2) = 4912$

$E_4=17+1+({E_4}^2) = 24127762$

$E_5=41+1+({E_5}^2) = 582148899128686$

> $E=E_5^{\frac{1}{2^5}}=2.893392257682316134127494663$

So we can obtain Euler's "Lucky" numbers as follows:

$Lucky_{n+1}=\lfloor E^{2^n}\rfloor-\lfloor E^{2^{n-1}}\rfloor^2+ \frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n)}$

$Lucky_1=\lfloor E^{2^0}\rfloor-\lfloor E^{2^{0-1}}\rfloor^2+ \frac{\lvert 0-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-0)}=2$

$Lucky_2=\lfloor E^{2^1}\rfloor-\lfloor E^{2^{1-1}}\rfloor^2+ \frac{\lvert 1-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-1)}=3$

$Lucky_3=\lfloor E^{2^2}\rfloor-\lfloor E^{2^{2-1}}\rfloor^2+ \frac{\lvert 2-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-2)}=5$

$Lucky_4=\lfloor E^{2^3}\rfloor-\lfloor E^{2^{3-1}}\rfloor^2+ \frac{\lvert 3-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-3)}=11$

$Lucky_5=\lfloor E^{2^4}\rfloor-\lfloor E^{2^{4-1}}\rfloor^2+ \frac{\lvert 4-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-4)}=17$

$Lucky_6=\lfloor E^{2^5}\rfloor-\lfloor E^{2^{5-1}}\rfloor^2+ \frac{\lvert 5-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-5)}=41$

The term

> $$\frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n)}$$

is just a correction (gently provided by @Steven Harding in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1837860/189215)) to calculate properly the initial case $Lucky_1$ associated with $n=0$ and join it to the rest of cases. The value $E_0$ is an special case because there is not previous term.

$\frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n)}=+1$ for $n=0$ and $=-1$ for the rest of cases.

Finally, replacing the expression into the Euler's "Lucky" polynomial, the result is the two variables function able to reproduce the complete set Euler primes ([OEIS A196230](https://oeis.org/A196230)):

> $$f(m,n)=m^2-m+[\lfloor E^{2^n} \rfloor - {\lfloor E^{2^{n-1}} \rfloor}^2 +\frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n)}]$$
>
> $$E = 2.893392257682316134127494663$$
>
> $$n\in[0,5] \in \Bbb N\ \ \ \ m = [1..(\lfloor E^{2^n} \rfloor  - {\lfloor E^{2^{n-1}} \rfloor}^2+\frac{\lvert n-(\frac{1}{2}) \rvert}{(\frac{1}{2})-n)})] \in \Bbb N$$

As a matter of curiosity proposed the constant decimal expansion as a new sequence at OEIS, and professor Sloane wisely considered that the use of a generating function has sense only for infinite sequences, so it does not make sense using a Mills-like constant to create a representing function for so very few terms because the expression is longer than the terms to be produced (the "Lucky" numbers $\{ 2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 41 \}$). I understood the reasons, but having that in mind, the generation of a two variable function able to produce the whole set of $57$ "Lucky" primes seemed interesting to me.

> I would like to ask the following question:
>
> 1. Are the calculations correct? Did I forget something?
> 2. Does it make sense an expression like this using a mathematical tool like Mills' constant for a finite sequence or is just a curious artificial "Frankenstein"-expression? Initially I understand that it is a curiosity only, but looking at the function it is interesting to see that there are two second degree terms. One depends on the variable $m$, the other one depends on the value $n$ associated to the constant $E$, so some diophantine relationship is there that could be explored. Thank you!