# Examples of other Mills' constants

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, constants

Mills' constant is the well-known constant A such that the function $\lfloor A^{{3}^{n}} \rfloor$ gives primes for all natural numbers $n$, whose value is ~$1.306377883...$

It is also well-known that there is an infinity of functions $\lfloor A^{{r}^{n}} \rfloor$ that gives primes for all $n$, depending on the value of $r$.

Are there any examples of such $\lfloor A^{{r}^{n}} \rfloor$ where $r \neq 3$? There seems to be very little information available on this subject.

Comment: It is easy enough to find such constants for $r\gt 3$.  Meanwhile, if Legendre's conjecture that there is a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ is true, then with $r=2$ you have $\lfloor 1.5246999605380943599233635756884211622202236231\ldots^{2^n}\rfloor$ giving primes: see [OEIS A059784](https://oeis.org/A059784)

Comment: "well known constant" among a very specially sampled part of the world's population...

Comment: @Henry Yes I heard of that result, thanks for the numerical example. Do you know of any other such examples for r!=3?

Comment: @Pickle - I have shown the initial digits for $r=4$ in an answer and the same method works for other $r$

Comment: @Pickle +1! this is one of my favorites topics!! I have made some variations of Mills-like constants in ordee to learn how it works. This other question might help you to get more ideas: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859996/a-function-can-provide-the-complete-set-of-euler-primes-via-a-mills-like-consta

Comment: @iadvd Thanks for the link, I am definitely going to read it! PS. looks like post could raise interest in the field, why not try to publish it?

Comment: @Pickle I am on it indeed! not for that question, but related with the topic. But I am not professional so it will be a long path to get it published. If I can publish I will let here a link... but it will take time yet! :) thanks for the words.

Comment: @iadvd Well then good luck! Let me know when it's published, I would certainly enjoy reading it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a particular value of $r \ge 3$, a high precision calculator and a method of finding the next prime above a number, it is easy to find the initial digits of $A_r$.

For example with $r=4$:

- start with the smallest prime $2$
- $2^4=16$
- the smallest prime above $16$ is $17$
- $17^4 = 83521$
- the smallest prime above $83521$ is $83537$
- etc.

We now want $2 \le A_4^{4^1} \lt 3$ and $17 \le A_4^{4^2} \lt 18$ and $83537 \le A_4^{4^3} \lt 83538$ and so on

This will give $A_4=1.193725\ldots$

Meanwhile, for $r=2$, then if Legendre's conjecture that there is a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ is true,  you have $\lfloor 1.5246999605380943599233635756884211622202236231…^{2^n}\rfloor$ giving primes: see [OEIS A059784](https://oeis.org/A059784)