# A formula for the first eleven primes: $ 2 \cdot (n + n / (27 / n)) + 1 / n - 1 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

So, just for kicks, and for an exercise, I've written an evolutionary algorithm to search for a prime number formula (I know, contain your laughter) that was limited to a set of operators and constants. My program came up with this:

$$ 2 \cdot (n + n / (27 / n)) + 1 / n - 1 $$

If $n$ is an integer such that $1 \leq n \leq 11$ and $/$ means the integer division such that $a / b = ⌊\frac{a}{b}⌋$, the above expression produces the first eleven prime numbers:

$$2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31$$

However broad my question may be, I cannot help but ask:

> Is there a pattern in this expression that could be efficiently extended for it to generate more primes? This is probably the case, but is it completely useless, for nothing more than mere coincidence?

Comment: what means "integer division"? You mean the operator $a//b:=\lfloor a/b\rfloor$ used in some programming languages?

Comment: @Masacroso Correct. Excuse me for the misunderstanding, I've made an edit.

Comment: I think it takes more information to write down that formula, than to individually list out all of the first 11 prime numbers ... so it doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: Is the meaning of / in the $1/n$ term also integer division? That would always be $0$ unless $n = 1$ right?

Comment: @Tob Ernack That is correct. I came to the conclusion that it was generated to make the first result $2$ instead of $1$. If we exclude the $1/n$ term, we're still left with $10$ primes, although preceded by a $1$.

Comment: There's a slightly similar idea in Sloane's A059999.

Comment: Does your code come up with any other expressions?  What's stopping your code from comming up with a formula for more primes?  What happens if you take out the floor operator?

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder Thank you for your interest. Unfortunately the code has been lost and I can't find it anymore. I recall trying various combinations of operators, and without the floor operator it didn't really come up with anything interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Hum. Let $p_i$ be the $i$-th prime and consider

$$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\cdot \left\lfloor\frac{n}i\right\rfloor$$

for some $k$. We have

\begin{align}
f(1)&=a_1\\
f(2)&=2a_1+a_2\\
f(3)&=3a_1+a_2+a_3\\
\dots
\end{align}

It's easy to see that

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
f(1)=p_1\\
f(2)=p_2\\
\vdots\\
f(k)=p_k
\end{array}
\right.$$

defines a system of linear equations on the $a_i$ which is uniquely solvable. In this manner, one can produce a formula that yields the first $k$ primes. This isn't quite similar to your formula, but it's something I guess.

Answer (score 2):

> Well, it is a nice curiosity, if you can use the evolutionary algorithm to generate a finite set of primes of your choice, then you can generate a function of two variables able to generate up to $63$ primes: the complete set of [Euler primes](https://oeis.org/A196230). Do as follows:

- I am supposing that your algorithm is a kind of "perceptron"-like (so it makes some steps taking as input the result of the previous step). So define as the target the set of [Euler lucky numbers](https://oeis.org/A014556), so your algorithm is intended to generate now the following primes:

$$2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 41$$

So your function will generate a similar expression like the one of your question, for instance let us call it $f(x)$ such that $f:[1..6] \to [2,3,5,11,17,41]$

- Now, define $F(x,n)$ as the following function:

$$F(x,n)=n^2-n+f(x)$$

- $F(x,n)$ will generate the complete set of $63$ Euler primes for $x \in [1..6], n \in [1..f(x)-1]$, because each $f(1)..f(6)$ generates the degree $0$ coefficient of one of the existing [Euler prime-generating polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_numbers_of_Euler).

If your algorithm is able to define the target of primes for a reduced set without getting very complex, then it will work. Indeed I did sometime ago something similar but using a [Mills-like constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859996/a-function-can-provide-the-complete-set-of-euler-primes-via-a-mills-like-consta).

Comment: Very interesting. We would end up with a simple enough expression able to generate 63 primes in total. This could also probably be done without a closed-form formula for $f(x)$, but I wonder if there exists $g(k)$ whose closed-form uses $F(x, n)$ in such a fashion that $g(k)$ will generate the primes in a strictly increasing order. Is it also the case that the 63 Euler primes generated by all these polynomials are strictly the first 63 primes, or are there gaps?

Comment: To elaborate on my algorithm, it was just a plain-stupid symbolic regression without any particular ingenuity, and I believe that its strength lied solely in the set of operations and constants choosed for it, as some layered integer divisions can produce pretty interesting motions. Alas, I've lost the code long ago, but I am most sure that a specialized implementation like this: http://www.cgplibrary.co.uk will fare more excellently than whatever code I had there. On the other hand, maybe given such a limited set like these lucky numbers, it might be easier to derive the formula by hand?

Comment: @PatrykCzachurski I would suggest you to try to write it again because it might have good ideas inside.The primes generated have gaps between them, each Euler polynomial generates a set of primes in increasing order, but with different gaps.So there is no total order in the final set of $63$ primes,only partial order for the primes associated to each polynomial.A formula by hand for $63$ primes would probably need an interpolation,that would lead to a big degree polynomial.There is a very well known prime-generating polynomial list: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Comment: @PatrykCzachurski by the way, definitely it was the first time I heard about Cartesian Genetic Programming but it sounds quite interesting! it seems like a neural network-like programming. The Perceptron I was mentioning is slightly different (and more simple) but basically the idea is the same: the system evolves from an input to a final output. Really interesting I took note of the link, thanks!